# Preprocessor like #if UNITY_ANDROID would run on android emulator?

Tags: android, mobile, unity-game-engine, preprocessor, emulation

My question is how to make sure the app is running from a mobile device and not over a emulator? Unity Preprocessor can tell the difference?

My code is something like this:

```
#if  UNITY_IPHONE
    Debug.Log("Running on Apple Device.");
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
    Debug.Log("Running on Android Device.");
#elif UNITY_WP8
    Debug.Log("Running on WP Device.");
#else
    Debug.Log("Not running on mobile Device.");
#endif
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not. As the [Unity3D Preprocessor documentation shows](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html), there are only defines for the device types.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That makes sens! So what are the workarounds?